# Error on installing contrib module to ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

Following the instructions at https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib I try running:

> ejabberdctl module_install ejabberd_auth_http

But the response I get is:

> Error: not available

Do I need to download the module to a specific place in the ejabberd install path for this to work, or is there some other step missing?

Comment: Did you try ejabberdctl modules_update_specs and then ejabberdctl modules_available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following sequence on ejabberd and it seems at least to install:

- Make sure ejabberd is started

  ```
  $ ./ejabberdctl start
  ```
- Download the list of available modules:

  ```
  $ ./ejabberdctl modules_update_specs
  ```
- Check available modules:

  ```
  $ ./ejabberdctl modules_available
  ```
- Install the module:

  ```
  $ ./ejabberdctl module_install ejabberd_auth_http
  src/ejabberd_auth_http.erl:11: Warning: behaviour ejabberd_gen_auth undefined
  ok
  ```

From there you should be able to configure it and restart ejabberd.

Reference: [Easy installer and structure for ejabberd contributed modules](https://blog.process-one.net/easy-installer-and-structure-for-ejabberd-contributed-modules/)

Comment: worked fine... though enabling "auth_method: http" does nothing... I'm getting the feeling that some of the quirkiness I'm experiencing could be due to it being in windows... I think I'll setup a Ubuntu VM and see how things go there

Comment: yeah... it's enabling now, but getting a crash... will continue on github

Comment: Thanks, I think the module rely on other dependencies that are not automatically installed by script.

Comment: I have the same problem! I have done all the steps, but modules_available does not return anything! any idea?